# Splitting char to multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, split, oracle-sqldeveloper

The table is as follows:

```
YEAR  | MONTH |            HOLIDAY            |
2015  |  10   | #      #      #    ###        |
2015  |  11   | #      #      #      #      # |
```

I want to create the following:

```
YEAR  | MONTH | DATE |  VALUE  |
2015  |   10  |  01  |    #    |
2015  |   10  |  02  |         |
2015  |   10  |  03  |         |
2015  |   10  |  04  |    #    |

              UNTIL
2016  |   11  |  30  |    #    |
```

I've seen a few solutions around stack but It couldn't work 
Any help would be greatly appreciating

Comment: This looks like you want to use `UNPIVOT` but an exact answer is not possible because you replaced your actual data with `#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why you would want to go to November 31st, a date that doesn't exist.  But, here is an idea:

```
with n as (
      select level as n
      from dual
      connect by level <= 31
     )
select t.year, t.month, n.n as day,
       substr(t.holidays, n.n, 1) as holiday
from t join
     n
     on n.n <= length(t.holiday);
```

Comment: Sorry, It was my bad, until November 30
Actually the length of holiday column in each month = length date of that month

Comment: @user3863074 . . . I figured that, which is why I use that in my answer.